# database connection, fetching rows and handling error in csharp

Tags: c#, sql-server

Fetching database records and displaying as JSON. Asking for revision to ensure if everything's ok, i.e. connections are properly handled and closed in case of error.

```
public class Department
{
    public Department(int id, String name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}


public List<Department> FindAllDepartment()
{
    List<Department> rows = new List<Department>();
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;pooling=true"))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees.dbo.Department", sqlConnection);
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                    rows.Add(new Department(sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0), sqlDataReader.GetString(1)));
            }
            return rows;
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit the title to state what the code functionally does, rather than technically?

Comment: Don't write ADO.NET code, use the likes of [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). ["if you’re writing ADO.Net code by hand, you’re stealing from your employer or client."](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/07/24/dont-write-your-own-orm/)

Comment: I don't want to give my employer or client something that has 300+ outstanding issues, https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues plain vanilla ADO, just crack it down and learn to code the right way and just repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>   using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;pooling=true"))
>   {
>       ...
>       }
>       finally
>       {
>           sqlConnection.Close();
>       }
>   }
> ```

You're correctly using a `using` statement for the connection, which will both close and dispose the connection when its scope finishes. So no need to explicit call `Close()`.

Almost (if not) every database related object implements `IDisposable` - including `SqlCommand`, so you should encapsulate that in a `using` as well.

All in all, your method should look like something like this:

```
public List<Department> FindAllDepartment()
{
  using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;pooling=true"))
  {
    sqlConnection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees.dbo.Department", sqlConnection))
    using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
      List<Department> rows = new List<Department>();
      while (sqlDataReader.Read())
      {
        rows.Add(new Department(sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0), sqlDataReader.GetString(1)));
      }

      return rows;
    }
  }
}
```

where the `using` statements handle the clean up - even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks, for `using (SqlCommand command`, are we missing braces?

Comment: @AppDeveloper: No, we're allowed to "stack" `using` statements as shown :-)

Comment: cool beans, very articulate. Can you refer me to any of your comprehensive insert, update or delete posts just for the sake of review.

Comment: @AppDeveloper: I'm not sure if I understand your question?

Comment: Asking for advice on code yet to be written or implemented is off-topic for this site. Even in a sneaky comment.